# include multiple node_modules in tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Migrating Angular 4.x to Angular 5 my project. I have faced

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/api-ai-javascript/index.ts
```

So i changed in tsconfig.json added below changes,

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "node_modules/api-ai-javascript/index.ts"
  ]
```

Still getting `/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts` How to added include multiple node_modules?

EDITED:

```
 "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    {"node_modules/api-ai-javascript/index.ts"},
    {"node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts"},
  ]
```

Getting `expected token } in JSON at position 439.`

Comment: how are you importing it in your typescript?

Comment: Edited.Pl check now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding the invalid json, it's because "include" must be an array of strings. Try that

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "node_modules/api-ai-javascript/index.ts",
    "node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts"
]
```

Answer (score -6):

Getting expected token } in JSON at position 439.

This means that something is wrong in the JSON file. Most likely it's the last comma after `stomp.service.ts"}` in

```
 "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    {"node_modules/api-ai-javascript/index.ts"},
    {"node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts"},
  ]
```

Comment: Still getting same execption